# Why did Jeanne kill Paul?

Tags: plot-explanation, last-tango-in-paris

In [Last Tango In Paris](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070849/), I did not think that Jeanne "loved" Paul but I thought she cared enough for him to not kill him. What was her reasoning?

Answer (score -1):

The movie doesn't provide an answer, we can only guess. For instance [this discussion in Slant magazine](https://www.slantmagazine.com/house/article/the-conversations-last-tango-in-paris/P2) tries to offer an explanation:

> EH: **It’s yet another moment where we’re left to wonder what Jeanne is
>   thinking**, and any of the motivations you suggest seem plausible for
>   this enigmatic woman. If I had to choose, **I’d say that Jeanne is most
>   disturbed by Paul’s flippant appropriation of her father’s military
>   cap. When Paul approaches her in that hat, it’s Jeanne’s opportunity
>   to kill a father** who, the film hints, seems to have had a lingering
>   impact on her life and her sexual identity: think of her mother’s very
>   funny line about the enduring erotic charge of her dead husband’s
>   boots, a sexual electricity that has transcended death (“They give me
>   strange shivers,” she says). As we’ve discussed, Jeanne’s psychology
>   isn’t examined as intently as Paul’s, but it’s clear that for her,
>   military power and fatherly authoritarianism and sexual pleasure are
>   all tangled together. **Certainly, killing fathers was very much on
>   Bertolucci’s mind at this point.** Two years earlier, in 1970, he’d
>   released a twinned pair of films about the often unwelcome power of
>   the father figure: *The Conformist*, in which Bertolucci cheekily gives
>   an assassination target the real-life Paris address and phone number
>   of the director’s cinematic father Jean-Luc Godard, and *The Spider’s
>   Stratagem*, in which the mystery of a father’s long-ago death reshapes
>   the life of his son.